# Pandas dataframe compression

Tags: python, pandas

How do I map one dataframe into another df with less number of rows summing values of rows whoose indices are in given interval?

For example

Given df:

```
      Survived
Age           
20           1
22           1
23           3
24           2
30           2
33           1
40           8
42           7
```

Desired df

(for interval = 5):

```
      Survived
Age           
20           7
25           0
30           3
35           0
40           15
```

(for interval = 10):

```
      Survived
Age           
20           7
30           3
40           15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function for the `groupby` argument:

```
In [6]: df.groupby(lambda x: x//10 * 10).sum()
Out[6]: 
    Survived
20         7
30         3
40        15
```

Note, this also works with 5 but it doesn't work the way you want with empty groups, that is, it doesn't fill in with zeroes!

```
In [12]: df.groupby(lambda x: x//5 *5).sum()
Out[12]: 
    Survived
20         7
30         3
40        15
```

However, if the data were to contain values for those groups in the 5 interval, you can see it is working.

```
In [18]: df
Out[18]: 
     Survived
Age          
20          1
22          1
23          3
24          2
26         99
30          2
33          1
40          8
42          7
47         99

In [19]: df.groupby(lambda x: x//5 *5).sum()
Out[19]: 
    Survived
20         7
25        99
30         3
40        15
45        99
```

Comment: @ОлегСериков Are you sure jezrael's solution isn't more what you need?

Comment: I think the best is try both solution and if output is same, use `juanpa.arrivillaga` solution, because no converting to `timedeltaindex`. If outputs are different, I think you can use my solution.

Answer (score 1):

First convert `int` index to `TimedeltaIndex` and then [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.resample.html):

```
df.index = pd.TimedeltaIndex(df.index.to_series(), unit='s')
print (df)
          Survived
00:00:20         1
00:00:22         1
00:00:23         3
00:00:24         2
00:00:30         2
00:00:33         1
00:00:40         8
00:00:42         7

df1 = df.resample('5S').sum().fillna(0)
df1.index = df1.index.seconds
print (df1)
    Survived
20       7.0
25       0.0
30       3.0
35       0.0
40      15.0

df2 = df.resample('10S').sum().fillna(0)
df2.index = df2.index.seconds
print (df2)
    Survived
20         7
30         3
40        15
```

EDIT:

If `Age` > 60 it works nice too:

```
print (df)
     Survived
Age          
20          1
22          1
23          3
24          2
30          2
33          1
40          8
42          7
60          8
62          7
70          8
72          7
```

```
df.index = pd.TimedeltaIndex(df.index.to_series(), unit='s')

df1 = df.resample('5S').sum().fillna(0)
df1.index = df1.index.seconds
print (df1)
    Survived
20       7.0
25       0.0
30       3.0
35       0.0
40      15.0
45       0.0
50       0.0
55       0.0
60      15.0
65       0.0
70      15.0

df2 = df.resample('10S').sum().fillna(0)
df2.index = df2.index.seconds
print (df2)
    Survived
20       7.0
30       3.0
40      15.0
50       0.0
60      15.0
70      15.0
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution is nice too, but is possible add solution for interval=5?

Comment: I edited my answer. Maybe the OP will find the results acceptable, but they do not conform exactly to the requested output like yours do. Although, now I wonder how yours will fair when Age > 60

Comment: Thank you. If use resample, it is no problem if Age is more as `60` - see edit.

Comment: Excellent! I really like this solution. Resampling is exactly the concept the OP was looking for, anyway, not "compression"

Comment: Yes, if OP has larger `df`, your solution works nice. But my solution is more general, works with smaller df and with missing intervals, where your solution fail.

Comment: @jezrael how would you do it if the index numbers have decimals? And instead you need to have 2; 2.05; 2.10  etc in the i dex? Can ask as new question maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an new column from the column `Age` and then use groupby:

In order to create the new column, `Age` needs to be taken out of the index:

```
df.reset_index(inplace = True)


def cat_age(age):
    return 10*int(age/10.)

df['category_age'] = df.Age.apply(lambda x: cat_age(x))
df.groupby('category_age',as_index = False).agg({'Survived':sum})
```

Output:

```
    category_age    Survived
0   20              7
1   30              3
2   40              15
```

Of course if you want to change the categories, you can pass the interval in `cat_age`:

```
def cat_age(age,interval)
    return interval*int(1.*age/interval)
```